# Variable from switch statement won't print

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Hey so I am writing a program for class, and do not know why my code is throwing the error: "use of unassigned local variable 'value'"

Here is my switch statement:

```
 switch (sType)
            {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Enter GPA: ");
                swag = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("Enter thesis title: ");
                cool = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.Write("Enter dissertation title: ");
                value = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                break;

        }
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

So basically I am just inputting this "sType", and the switch works, but when I go to print out the value variable i get the "use of unassigned local variable 'value'" error.

Comment: Where you declared "value" variable ?

Comment: Well, presumably not every `switch` branch assigns a value to the `value`, hence depending on the `sType` value you may end up having `value` unassigned.

Comment: its in the beginning this is just a snippit of code.
I did it like this:

Comment: string sID, zip, thesis, value;

Comment: The "value" variable has no inicialization / value attribution in your algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise the variable value where you have defined it.

```
string value = string.empty;
```

Just in case, what if case 3 is not executed in the program. So, `value` remained uninitialised throughout the program. But, in all cases, at the end, you are writing the value of `value` in the last line, which would be null.

So, compiler throws an error, that the variable value should be initialised before printing its value.

---

<sub>*NOTE : You must assign some value to ***local variables*** before they are being used somewhere.</sub>

Comment: this is just a snipit of code i declared at the beginning with   string sID, zip, thesis, value;

Comment: @jdoe = initialise *at least* variable `value` with `string sID, zip, thesis, value=string.empty;`

Answer (score 2):

`value` doesn't appear to be defined/initialized. Above your switch statement you should have

```
var value = "";
```

Comment: @un-lucky I provided an answer to his question so how is it not an answer?

Comment: I'm aware of the policy. He doesn't have a variable defined/initialized so he's getting an error. Ergo, my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sID, zip, thesis, value; 
sID = zip = thesis = value = string.Empty;
```